# How to make the android intent load faster?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

In my app i'm making a work around for some particular part where instead of calling the fragment i am calling an intent, But compared to the fragment load the intent load up time is very slow.

> I have used thing part of code in my navigation drawer class, when the particular item is pressed it performs the following activities

Here is the part of my code:

```
switch(position)
            {
                case 0 :
                    int DELAY = 0;

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, DELAY);

                    break;
                case 1 :fragment = new OverviewFragment();
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 2 :fragment = new StatisticsFragment();
                    break;
                case 3 :fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    break;
                case 4 :fragment = new ReportUsFragment();
                    break;
            }
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

> **Please let me know how to make the intent appear as soon as the button is click i.e even before the navigation drawer is closed or called back the page should be on the background just like the fragments**

Answer (score 0):

You're calling startActivity in the intent on a delay.  Remove the delay.  Better yet, remove the entire runnable and just call it directly (unless this is on a thread of course).

Comment: That's as fast as you can get it.  There is no magic to make it go faster, Android is a complex system and a lot of lifecycle functions need to be called to launch an activity.

Comment: isn't there a way around?
will you please look at this question(The current code is a way around for this question issue) :: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240810/issue-onclick-navigation-drawer-items-creates-new-fragments-unable-to-start-th